# ActiveRecord Query Conversion from Rails 2 to Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am used to Rails 2 and have an existing query:

```
@players = Player.find(
  :all,
  :select => 'players.*, positions.name AS "position_name"',
  :joins => 'LEFT JOIN positions ON positions.id = players.position_id',
  :conditions => ['status IN (?, ?, ?, ?)', 'd', 'i', 'n', 'u']
)
```

I am trying to write the Rails 4 equivalent but I get an error `unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end` which is the closing bracket of the query.

```
@players = Player
  .select('players.*, positions.name AS "position_name"')
  .joins('LEFT JOIN positions ON positions.id = players.position_id')
  .where(status: ['d', 'i', 'n', 'u'])
)
```

I've tried reading the docs but can't see where I'm going wrong.

Also, if this were using the `params` hash instead of hardcoded values, would the above not be liable to sql injection, if so, how would it be written to use placeholders like the first Rails 2 query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the last `)`; that is an extra with the way the new query is structured.

```
@players = Player
  .select('players.*, positions.name AS "position_name"')
  .joins('LEFT JOIN positions ON positions.id = players.position_id')
  .where(status: ['d', 'i', 'n', 'u'])
```

will be considered as below without the new lines:

```
@players = Player.select('players.*, positions.name AS "position_name"').joins('LEFT JOIN positions ON positions.id = players.position_id').where(status: ['d', 'i', 'n', 'u'])
```

Comment: ah, can't believe I missed that, thanks for your help.